# create a login or user with sa permissions or existing ones escalated to sa

Tags: sql-server, permissions

If someone in SQL Server, creates a login or user with sa permissions or existing login or user permission escalated to sa. I need to get the details in to the table who are escalated to sa permission and logins or users with sa permissions recently created on a daily basis

Comment: What is the version of sql server that you are using?